# Precompiled header define map unavailable

Tags: c++, visual-studio, precompiled-headers, incredibuild

I am using Visual Studio 2005 and incredibuild. I get this error for one of my projects:

> Fatal error:
>
> Task queue management failed.
>        <- Precompiled header define map unavailable (x:\dev\ib\VCDepEvalTask.pas, line 373)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Difficult (if not impossible) to tell with information given.

Comment: Did you google the error message? It's mentioned in, for instance, IncrediBuild release notes.

Comment: What other information do you need?

Comment: Yes I have google the error message and could find any relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled upon this bug in VS2008, Incredibuild 7.31 build 1814

the reason was:

There was one library (a.lib) with a project dependency to another library (b.lib), the b.lib project contained a setting for precompile=off for only one file but not for the whole project.

First i fixed just that precompile setting (removed from vcproj), -> no changes.
Then i removed that depency between a.lib and b.lib => everything OK

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are using an older version of IncrediBuild. This issues was already fixed in IncrediBuild more than a year ago.
Can you please let me know if this issue still persists in the latest IncrediBuild version or whether the latest IncrediBuild version solved your problem?

Disclaimer, the writer is an IncrediBuild employee.